# Giving table rows a solid, continuous background color

Tags: css

I am using a table with 1 column and three rows.  I would like to give all 3 rows a solid, continuous background color.  How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
    echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">"; 

    echo '<tr class="class2">';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2name"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 9):

If you collapse the borders and put no spacing between it will make a solid background.

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/HpQjd/

Comment: Thanks, but since this table is part of a PHP query, I want there to be white spacing between each result, one result being the three rows listed above.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you just said. Is a result a full table, or just a tr?

Answer (score 1):

This will make the column have a blue background and black border on the sides.

```
.samplesrec
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.samplesrec td
{
  border: 0px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... would this make a continuous background for the column through all three rows?

Comment: it should.  gets rid of spacing and only has borders on the sides.  You can mess with it to get it to look how you want.  obviously the blue background won't do.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.sitename1
{
   background-color: xxx;
   border-left: 1px solid xxx;
   border-right: 1px solid xxx;
}
```

maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just apply a background-color to your entire table? I don't have time to test, unfortunately.

```
.samplesrec{
  background-color:#XXX;
}
```